# Kubernates Horizontal Pod Autoscaling - set stackdriver as custom metrics?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Asking the question here, since there is no sufficient documentation available.

I have the `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` configuration like this below, I want to auto scale instances based on custom metrics provided by gke(google container engine) stackdriver monitoring. I want to scale based on number of requests.

```
  metrics:
  - type: Object
    object:
      metricName: requests-per-second
      target:
        apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
        kind: Ingress
        name: main-route
      targetValue: 25
```

Comment: [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-custom-metrics) shows no support for stackdriver metrics. And you need to activate alpha feature for custom metrics.

Comment: This would be an awesome feature, hopefully it gets fully supported.